# How to join table with itself to receive only balances of new users?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have one table with balances, which contains let's say only user_id, balance_amount and balance_date. I would like to get only balances of "new" people so from table1. Is my logic correct?

```
SELECT
  bgnb1."user_id" as user_id1,
  bgnb2."user_id" as user_id2,
  bgnb1."total balance across all account"
FROM "bi_german_negative_balance" bgnb1
LEFT JOIN "bi_german_negative_balance" bgnb2 ON bgnb1."user_id"=bgnb2."user_id"
WHERE bgnb1."balance_date" = dateadd(day, -2, CURRENT_DATE)
  AND bgnb2."balance_date" = dateadd(day, -90, CURRENT_DATE)
  AND bgnb2."user_id" IS NULL
```

In the new table I didn't receive any unmatched record from table2, which is strange for me - the table is just empty.

Comment: Please Edit your question and include sample rows from both tables, together with a sample of the output you would like to receive. Also, let us know what you mean by "new people".

Comment: I would like to have "new" which are all from the left table (bgnb1) and NULL in table bgnb2, which means that they were not active 3 months ago, but active 2 days ago and basing on this condition i want to sum balances. Unfortunately, this query above is not returning me anything.

Comment: Please Edit your question and include sample rows from both tables, together with a sample of the output you would like to receive, given those sample input tables.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have used left join is right.. only may be your date condition is not satisfied.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iRy7xCRVdSKmF5qD6yspPy/0

Working fiddle. you can try out there